# Inherit Type Member Entity Typescript

Tags: generics, inheritance, typescript, angular

I have the following data structure:

```
export abstract class Person {
    ...
}

export class FPerson extends Person {
    a: A;
    b: B;
}

export class JPerson extends Person {
    c: C;
}

export class User {
    person: Person;
}
```

On server side I have the same structure written with java, the User person member can be either `FPerson` or `JPerson`. I want be able to cast it according the person type.. How can I do that in Typescript?

Something like that:

```
doSomething(u: User) {
    let fp: FPerson;
    let jp: JPerson;

    if (u.person.isFPerson()) {
       fp = <FPerson> u.person;
    } else {
       jp =  <FPerson> u.person;
    }
  ...
}
```

How can I implement the `isFPerson()` method? And how can I force typescript the store the extra fields present in `FPerson` and `JPerson` into a `Person` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like in java:

```
doSomething(u: User) {
    let fp: FPerson;
    let jp: JPerson;

    if (u.person instanceof FPerson) {
       fp = <FPerson> u.person;
    } else {
       jp = <JPerson> u.person;
    }
  ...
}
```

Though both `FPerson` and `JPerson` need to extend `Person`, which isn't the case in the code in your question.